# How can I merge many documents into a single document and move to another collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following situation:

- 50 Documents in one collection
- Want to move the into 1 Document

```
day: {data:data,data:data}
day: {data:data,data:data}
```

This data should become:

```
week:[day,day,day..]
```

This is a one time job. I want to do it in the command line or Robomongo.

Comment: Can you please give examples of exactly how your documents are formatted and also exactly how you expect the result to appear. Your examples are a little too abstract to understand the format of your data.

Comment: Does it really matter how the data is formatted? It is complex, deeply nested stuff, with arrays and what not. I just want to make all of it childs of a parent doc.

Comment: It would help.. but I've posted an answer that may be helpful to you.

Comment: Have you looked at using the aggregation framework or map-reduce? Both are well suited for this. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we can't see your exact document structure, I'll try to give a simple solution that should work no matter what structure your documents have.

Basically you would want to iterate over each of the documents in the source collection and generate an array of all the values.

```
week_array = []
db.source_col.find({}).forEach( function( doc ){
  week_array.push( doc );
} );
```

You now have an array containing all the documents from the source_collection. All you have to do now is construct a new document and insert the array into it at the correct attribute:

```
var week_doc = { "week": week_array };
```

Now just insert it into the target collection:

```
db.target_col.insert( week_doc );
```