# Merging multiple documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have here a collection of two documents in a mongodb database (I am using robomongo)[image: list of documents in my collection]

I took the solution from
[How can I merge many documents into a single document and move to another collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020038/how-can-i-merge-many-documents-into-a-single-document-and-move-to-another-collec)

However I am ending up empty

[image: error]

The code of the original documents are as follows:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5534e79726092822df7528ff"),
"labels" : {
    "urls" : "http://planet-e.nethttp://planetecommunications.bandcamp.comhttp://www.discogs.com/user/planetedetroithttp://www.facebook.com/planetedetroithttp://www.flickr.com/photos/planetedetroithttp://plus.google.com/100841702106447505236http://myspace.com/planetecomhttp://myspace.com/planetedetroithttp://soundcloud.com/planetedetroithttp://twitter.com/planetedetroithttp://vimeo.com/user1265384http://www.youtube.com/user/planetedetroithttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_E_Communications",
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "Planet E",
    "sublabels" : "Antidote (4)Community ProjectsGuilty PleasuresI Ner Zon SoundsPlanet E Communications, Inc.TWPENTY",
    "contactinfo" : "Planet E Communications\nP.O. Box 27218\nDetroit, 48227, USA\n\np: 313.874.8729 \nf: 313.874.8732\n\nemail: info AT Planet-e DOT net\n",
    "profile" : "Classic Techno label from Detroit, USA.\n[b]Label owner:[/b] [a=Carl Craig].\n",
    "dataquality" : "Needs Vote"
}
}


 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5534e79726092822df752900"),
"labels" : {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "Earthtones Recordings",
    "sublabels" : [],
    "contactinfo" : "Seasons Recordings\n2236 Pacific Avenue\nSuite D\nCosta Mesa, CA  92627\n\ntel: +1.949.574.5255\nfax: +1.949.574.0255\n\nemail: <a href=\"mailto:jthinnes@seasonsrecordings.com\">jthinnes@seasonsrecordings.com</a>\n",
    "profile" : "California deep house label founded by Jamie Thinnes. Now defunct and continued as [l=Seasons Recordings].",
    "dataquality" : "Correct",
    "urls" : "http://www.seasonsrecordings.com/"
}
}
```

I want to combine both the documents as one document under one title "label"

Comment: Images are great if accompanied by actual code, can you please edit your question to include the documents schema and what you expect.

Comment: I edited it. But the original post stated that the schema is irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code snippet:

```
var label_array = [];
db.labels.find().forEach(function (doc){
    label_array.push(doc.labels);
});
db.label.insert({"label": label_array});
db.label.find();
```

**Result**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55353a2d6056a9466b1a3a9c"),
    "label" : [ 
        {
            "urls" : "http://planet-e.nethttp://planetecommunications.bandcamp.comhttp://www.discogs.com/user/planetedetroithttp://www.facebook.com/planetedetroithttp://www.flickr.com/photos/planetedetroithttp://plus.google.com/100841702106447505236http://myspace.com/planetecomhttp://myspace.com/planetedetroithttp://soundcloud.com/planetedetroithttp://twitter.com/planetedetroithttp://vimeo.com/user1265384http://www.youtube.com/user/planetedetroithttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_E_Communications",
            "id" : "1",
            "name" : "Planet E",
            "sublabels" : "Antidote (4)Community ProjectsGuilty PleasuresI Ner Zon SoundsPlanet E Communications, Inc.TWPENTY",
            "contactinfo" : "Planet E Communications\nP.O. Box 27218\nDetroit, 48227, USA\n\np: 313.874.8729 \nf: 313.874.8732\n\nemail: info AT Planet-e DOT net\n",
            "profile" : "Classic Techno label from Detroit, USA.\n[b]Label owner:[/b] [a=Carl Craig].\n",
            "dataquality" : "Needs Vote"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "name" : "Earthtones Recordings",
            "sublabels" : [],
            "contactinfo" : "Seasons Recordings\n2236 Pacific Avenue\nSuite D\nCosta Mesa, CA  92627\n\ntel: +1.949.574.5255\nfax: +1.949.574.0255\n\nemail: <a href=\"mailto:jthinnes@seasonsrecordings.com\">jthinnes@seasonsrecordings.com</a>\n",
            "profile" : "California deep house label founded by Jamie Thinnes. Now defunct and continued as [l=Seasons Recordings].",
            "dataquality" : "Correct",
            "urls" : "http://www.seasonsrecordings.com/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55353bba6da1f1bc6aaec7c2"),
    "label" : []
}

Comment: @DhirajEadara My apologies, I forgot to change the source collection name. Please check my edit and try again.

Comment: @DhirajEadara No worries :-)